# paginate 'nested' rails routes for seo

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, kaminari

I need to figure out how to properly use routes to create a url structure like so:

items/page/2

items/expired/page/2

I have items/page/2 working and then I have this which I want to to correct: 
items/expired?page=2

I am using Kaminari to provide pretty url structure for rails 4.2 with a concern.
https://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari/#creating-friendly-urls-and-caching

My controller has two actions: index and expired

My views under items are index.html.haml and expired.html.haml

routes.rb

```
concern :paginatable do
  get '(page/:page)', :action => :index, :on => :collection, :as => ''
end

concern :expired_paginatable do
  get '(page/:page)', :action => :expired, :on => :collection, :as => ''
end

get 'items/expired', to: "items#expired", :concerns => :expired_paginatable
resources :items, :concerns => :paginatable
```

my views both have:

```
= paginate @items
```

I know I do not need two concerns but thought I would try it.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up changing my resources block to this:

```
resources :items do
  collection do
    get 'expired/page/:page', :action => :expired
    get :expired
  end
  concerns :paginatable
end
```

dropping:

```
concern :expired_paginatable do
  get '(page/:page)', :action => :expired, :on => :collection, :as => ''
end

get 'items/expired', to: "items#expired", :concerns => :expired_paginatable
resources :items, :concerns => :paginatable
```